# kivy xcode 7 issue - build and archive works, but validation fails

Tags: python, ios, xcode, validation, kivy

I've created an iOS app on kivy. After building and archiving the app in xcode 7 I cannot validate the app.

Specifically, validation fails with the following error message:

```
"Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for audio_sdl2.so.o"
```

The message also reads:

```
"Unable to validate your application.
The archive is invalid. /var/folders/blahblahblah/Packages/myfile.ipa does not exist."
```

I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a while now without any luck. Does anyone know what is happening here or has anyone else experienced this issue? Is this a toolchain issue?

Comment: Alright so I upgraded to the new toolchain.py, which allows me to build and pass validation without error. However, there is still an issue when I try to upload to the app store.

The upload fails with the following error:
"ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file '.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/weakproxy.so.o' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles..."

There are a few of these errors. Has anyone else hit this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post the solution for future users who encounter this issue. It appears that the "dist" folder in kivy-ios has 30 or more .so.o files scattered throughout it that have been leftover from building shared libraries. If you go in and simply remove these .so.o files you can successfully validate and upload your app to the app store.

You can fix this issue by running the following script in your kivy-ios folder:

```
def kivy_ios_clean(file_ext, dir_to_clean, collection_dir='cleanup_collection'):
    '''
    inputs:
    - file_ext = extension of the file that you want to move out of kivy-ios (ex: .so.o)
    - dir_to_clean = name of directory that needs cleaning

    other:
    - collection_dir = name of directory where all of the removed files will be collected (feel free to modify this script to delete files instead, I implemented it this way so you could see everything...)
    '''
    import os, shutil

    # Make folder for .so.o collection:
    if not os.path.exists(collection_dir):
        os.makedirs(collection_dir)

    # Parse the directory, move the files with the extension of interest to the collection folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_to_clean):
        for i in files:
            if file_ext in i:
                shutil.move(root+'/'+i, collection_dir)

kivy_ios_clean('.so.o', 'dist')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it was due to having `pip install`ed `py2app` unnecessarily into my kivy-ios setup. Removing it solved it for me.